# git diff get files changes with type of change, additions and deletions

Tags: git

I want to know anyway, we can get the diff between two commits with files names along with type of change(A addition, D deleted), additions (10 lines added) and deletions (-5 lines deleted)

I have tried `git diff --name-status 5021ea5b 62720bb8` this is not giving me the additions and deletions

also tried `git diff --numstat 5021ea5b 62720bb8` this is not giving me the type of change.

I want to populate data similar to github diff page.

[image]

Comment: What does wrong with `--numstat`?

Comment: @VladimirKovpak in `--numstat` i am not able to get whether file is added or deleted or modified

Comment: But git don't track creation or deletion of files (as far as I know), git tracks only changes performed. So if you create file, git will write something like: `1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)`, moreover github will show same...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--stat`, it will provide something like:

```
git diff --stat 43eae78 d296892
 config/services.php | 19 ++++++-------------
 1 file changed, 6 insertions(+), 13 deletions(-)
```

So here you can see what particular file was changed, how many insertions and deletions was performed.

Also you can use `--numstat` (as you did it):

```
git diff --numstat 43eae78 d296892
6       13      config/services.php
```

Here you can see same information, but little bit contracted. First column - insertions, 2nd - deletions, 3d - file name.